# Filter by results of select

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I am trying to translate the following query to peewee:

```
select count(*) from A where
id not in (select distinct package_id FROM B)
```

What is the correct Python code? So far I have this:

```
A.select(A.id).where(A.id.not_in(B.select(B.package_id).distinct()).count()
```

This code is not returning the same result. A and B are large 10-20M rows each. I can't create a dictionary of existing package_id items in the memory.

For example, this takes lot of time:

```
A.select(A.id).where(A.id.not_in({x.package_id for x in B.select(B.package_id).distinct()}).count()
```

May be LEFT JOIN?

Update: I ended up calling database.execute_sql()

Comment: @S3DEV I do not find an example of filter based on a table returned by select. The Python code above is not returning the same amount or rows.  `B.select` returns rows. Tables A and B are large - 10M entries each.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL:

```
select count(*) from A where
id not in (select distinct package_id FROM B)
```

Equivalent peewee:

```
q = (A
     .select(fn.COUNT(A.id))
     .where(A.id.not_in(B.select(B.package_id.distinct()))))
count = q.scalar()
```